# \. operator in Swift

Tags: swift, combine

Trying to learn the Combine framework and this operator is popping up: \.

```
Subscribers.Assign(object: lastPostLabel, keyPath: \.text)
```

I don't know what to call it to search for it. Anyone have a reference?

Comment: This is a Swift keyPath. There are plenty of articles about them. [Here is one of them](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-power-of-key-paths-in-swift/)

Comment: Does anyone know how I could've searched SO for "\." without knowing the term, keypath?

Cancel that: "backslash dot" gets you there. Apologies

Answer (score 1):

With with subscriber you can assign an output value of publisher to some object property using key path, like in below example

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var text: String = "loading" // property

    private var task: AnyCancellable?

    func fetch() {
        task = Just("done") // ... like long operation here
            .delay(for: 1, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.text, on: self) // equivalent to self.text = "done"
    }
}
```